# CodeDeploy to ECS container name not found, but configuration seems correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-fargate

I am using AWS code pipeline in order to deploy a built docker image to ecs (fargate).

As you can see below, the imagedefinitions.json file created by the build points to a docker container by the name `staging-core-api`.

You will also note below that the task definition for the service linked to this deployment contains a docker image by the same name.

I have triple checked that the URI specified in imagedefinitions.json is correct.

From what I understand this is all that should be required in order for ecs to retrieve the docker image. However I keep getting the following error after deployment failure:

```
Invalid action configuration
The AWS ECS container staging-core-api does not exist
```

The situation seems simple enough and it's totally unclear to me how to proceed in debugging the problem. Any insight would be very appreciated.

I attached the relevant files including the buildspec for the build below:

**imagedefinitions.json**

```
[{"name":"staging-core-api","imageUri":"263512868235.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging-core-api:369a521"}]
```

**buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' $CONTAINER_NAME $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
      - cat imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json
```

**taskdefinition.json**

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::263512868235:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/core-api",
          "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "263512868235.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging-core-api",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "staging-core-api"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:263512868235:task-definition/core-api:2",
  "family": "core-api",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 2,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the ecs service configuration was using an old task definition instead of the latest one. If you feel like everything looks like it's configured right and you're getting this error message check to make sure your service is using the updated task definition. Keep in mind that when you create new task definitions it does not automatically start using them, or ask whether you would like to.